# Search for a sub-string within a string

Tags: c#

I am really a beginner, I already know

```
string.indexOf("");
```

Can search for a whole word, but when I tried to search for `e.g: ig out of pig, it doesn't work`.

I have a similar string here(part of):

```
<Special!>The moon is crashing to the Earth!</Special!>
```

Because I have a lot of these in my file and I just cannot edited all of them and add a space like:

```
< Special! > The moon is crashing to the Earth! </ Special! >
```

I need to get the `sub-string` of Special! and The moon is crashing to the Earth!
What is the simple way to search for a part of a word without adding plugins like `HTMLAgilityPack`?

Comment: `IndexOf`...  You just most probably using it wrong, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IndexOf will work, you are probably just using it improperly.

If your string is in a variable call mystring you would say mystring.IndexOf and then pass in the string you are looking for.

```
string mystring = "somestring";
int position = mystring.IndexOf("st");
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you using it? You should use like this:

```
string test = "pig";
int result = test.IndexOf("ig");
// result = 1
```

If you want to make it case insensitive use

```
string test = "PIG";
int result = test.IndexOf("ig", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
// result = 1
```

- [String.IndexOf Method - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
string s = "<Special!>The moon is crashing to the Earth!</Special!>";
int whereMyStringStarts = s.IndexOf("moon is crashing");
```

`IndexOf` should work with spaces too, but maybe you have `new line` or `tab` characters, not spaces?

Sometimes case-sensitivity is important. You may control it by additional parameter called `comparisonType`. Example:

```
 int whereMyStringStarts = s.IndexOf("Special", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

More information about `IndexOf`: [String.IndexOf Method at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425.aspx)

Anyway, I think you may need regular expressions to create better parser. IndexOf is very primitive method and you may stuck in big mess of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
   string page = "<Special!>The moon is crashing to the Earth!</Special!>";
        if (page.Contains("</Special!>"))
        {
            pos = page.IndexOf("<Special!>");
            propertyAddress = page.Substring(10, page.IndexOf("</Special!>")-11);
            //i used 10 because <special!> is 10 chars, i used 11 because </special!> is 11
        }
```

This will give you "the moon is crashing to the earth!"